# Spring - Execute before web requests is finished and RequestMapping get's triggered

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm looking for a way to execute something before the RequestMapping call. To be a bit more descriptive I have a controller for file uploads like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ul")
public class UploadController
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{ticket}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ul(ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("ticket") String ticket)
    {
      ...
```

everything works fine so far. My problem is now, I use upload tickets to validate if the user can upload a file and these tickets have a limited lifetime, when the user uploads a really large file or from bad connection and this will take a few minutes the ticket will most likely be invalid and the upload dropped.

Is there a any way to implement something to get notified when the connection is established? Like when the URL is called so I can validate the ticket directly and maybe even can close the connection?

I already tried an interceptor, abstract controller, commons multipart resolver with progress listener but all this is to late and the events get triggered when the action (file transfer) is done.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use filters or executors for this purpose, filters come with servlet container and can be used to manipulate the request, executors come with the spring-mvc framework, there are several executors

> which gives us a cutaway points at different phases

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried the filter approach but the "doFilter" event gets triggered after the request completed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I added a UploadSecurity class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, and in the config I did:         http.antMatcher("/ul/**").addFilterBefore(new UploadFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS);

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have got it to work now!

I created an UploadFilter class:

```
@Component
public class UploadFilter implements Filter
{

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
    {

    }

}
```

and added a FilterRegistrationBean to the upload configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class UploadConfiguration
{

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement()
    {
        MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("2000MB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("2000MB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean uploadFilter()
    {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegBean.setFilter(new UploadFilter());
        filterRegBean.addUrlPatterns("/ul/*");
        filterRegBean.setEnabled(Boolean.TRUE);
        filterRegBean.setName("uploadFilter");
        filterRegBean.setAsyncSupported(Boolean.TRUE);
        filterRegBean.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1);
        return filterRegBean;
    }

}
```

The only thing that is still a mystery to me is the filter order, i had to pick a very low value to get it to work...